# Magento SEO URL's suddenly changed, can't reenable

Tags: .htaccess, url, magento, seo

I’m fairly new to the Magento platform but I have a decent amount of experience in web development on apache servers.

A few days ago I was asked to look into an issue that was first made aware of with failing filters.

I had a look at the google analytics data and it seems the SEO friendly URLs have all stopped displaying. The navigation URLs still use friendly words however on the page return the URL is redirected to a basic catalog URL.

http://www.camera-camera.com/cameras-and-accessories.html

instead now it goes to

https://www.camera-camera.com/index.php/catalog/category/view/id/9

I checked the admin config. The Web > SEO URL rewrites are set to YES 
I toggled them to No saved and back to yes then saved. Tried clearing the catalog URL rewrite cache

Checked the htaccess file and it hasn’t been touched for months.

Emptied the core rewrite table and reindexed it.

So I’m outta ideas now, was hoping some of you more experienced users can have some input as to what else I can check.

I also found it strange that the URL is now ignoring postback parameters. If you look at their filters they are simply an a link to the same page with a post parameter. This gets striped and ignored now might be related?

A file restore was on the day it happened.  Any files I should check it against?

Thanks for any help you can provide !

Comment: What status of `Catalog URL Rewrites` Index? You can find it under `System->Index Management`. Seems like you need refresh it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'ves been reindexed already.  Currently green "Ready"

Comment: Somebody tamper with the settings on your web server and disable mod_rewrite? Or deleted the .htaccess file in Magento's root folder?

Comment: Hi, as mentioned the htaccess file is still there. I did a compare to the default htaccess and didn't see much difference except the server RAM is 128MB. A missing htaccess would return a 404 wouldn't it?

Comment: Check if mod_rewrite is active

Comment: Did you take a look at Admin -> System -> Config -> Web -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use URL Rewrites (set to yes). Also you may want to take a look at Admin -> Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management

Comment: I just discovered that it was related to HTTPS.  I didn't notice but seems the site keeps redirecting to HTTPS even though the filter links etc are pointing to HTTP, in the redirect the parameters are dropped.  Now to figure out why its going into HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that it was related to HTTPS. I didn't notice but seems the site keeps redirecting to HTTPS even though the filter links etc are pointing to HTTP, in the redirect the parameters are dropped. Now to figure out why its going into HTTPS